# How to use SharpSVN in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, sharpsvn

Trying to use use SharpSVN in an ASP.NET app.  So far, it's been nothing but trouble.  First, I kept getting permission errors on "lock" files (that don't exist), even though NETWORK SERVICE has full permissions on the directories.  Finally in frustration I just granted Everyone full control.  Now I get a new error:

OPTIONS of 'https://server/svn/repo': authorization failed: Could not authenticate to server: rejected Basic challenge (https://server)

This happens whether I have the DefaultCredentials set below or not:

```
using (SvnClient client = new SvnClient())
{
    //client.Authentication.DefaultCredentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "password");
    client.LoadConfiguration(@"C:\users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\Subversion");

    SvnUpdateResult result;
    client.Update(workingdir, out result);
}
```

Any clues?  I wish there was SOME documentation with this library, as it seems so useful.

Comment: What happens when you enable the credentials line? That's what the error indicates as the problem.

Comment: Same error whether that line is commented out or not.

Comment: are you sure you're using the correct username and pass, ie can you connect to https://server/svn/repo using a browser?

Comment: Holy cow. You nailed it.  Password had not been updated on the server.  I wonder why my other SVN clients worked!?!  Thanks dude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user you need to grant permission is most likely the ASPNET user, as that's the user the ASP.NET code runs as by default.

Comment: Answer is in above comments, but going to mark this one correct so Sander gets credit.

Answer (score 0):

ASPNET user is a local account, preferably youd'd want to run this code in an Impersonate block, using a network account set up for this specific reason

Comment: Is that not what the Authentication.DefaultCredentials are for?  Am I using it incorrectly?

Comment: Authentication.DefaultCredentials is for authentication against the repository, the user running the website needs read/write access to `workingDir`