# How to pass my domain credentials to SVN server using SharpSVN

Tags: c#, sharpsvn

It may be a possibly duplicate question and may relate to 
[SVN Repository Authentication using SharpSVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099392/svn-repository-authentication-using-sharpsvn)

but I have tried the solution present in the above mentioned post but still I am getting 401 (Authorization Required) from my svn server.

Can somebody please point me where I am going wrong?
thanks in advance.

Comment: What about this? Does this helps you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563604/how-to-use-sharpsvn-in-asp-net

Comment: Nope, had gone through almost every post on stackoverflow related to SharpSVN but no luck.

Comment: Tried contacting or going through devl docs of SharpSVN?